# How to search fields uniquely by their value mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Actually I'm trying to make distinct search by `field_value`.

For example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa83007d5f5f84350af30c7"),
"_tag" : "hi"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa83007d5f5f80450af30c8"),
"_tag" : "hello"
 },
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("6aa83007d5f5f80450af30c8"),
"_tag" : "hello"
 },
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa83007d5f5f80450ar30c7"),
"_tag" : "bye"
 },
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa83117d5f5f80450ar30c7"),
"_tag" : "bye"
 }
```

In this context the following query is returning ["hi","hello","bye]

Query:

```
 db.collection("tags").distinct("_tag",function(err, result) {
                        if(err) throw err;
                          console.log(result)

                        db.close();
                    });
```

But what I'm asking is **How can i serch by the values i.e "hi" or "hello" etc disctinctively?**

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more ? What is your input and what is your expected response ?

Comment: @Veeram sir I'm asking how can I make a search query for distinct values

Comment: Something like `db.collection("tags").find({"_tag":{$in:["hi","hello","bye]})` ?

Comment: @Veeram but it's not giving unique results

Comment: Try Something like `db.collection("tags").distinct("_tag", {"_tag":{$in:["hi","hello","bye]})`

Comment: Hi user8027365 ; rather than answering in the comments, it would be better to clarify your answer by [edit]ing it to include all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `$in` to keep only those tags you want and then `$group` with [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to get unique values:

```
db.tags.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_tag": {$in:["hi","hello"] } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, _tags: { $addToSet: "$_tag" } } }
])
```